# C# WS Client avoid null value serialization

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a problem with a SOAP webclient, created automatically through 'add new service reference' option.
Service is generated from JAVA-CXF, and in my proxy class, it has a signature like this:

```
            public generatedClassResponse search (string p1, long p2);
```

p2 parameter is optional, so I need to modify my class. I've changed the type to long? and now, I've receiving an error from service: Unmarshalling error when serializing "" value.

My request autogenerated class is:

```
public class searchRequest {
   //omitted non param const

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="searchEvents", WrapperNamespace="http://test.com/", IsWrapped=true)]

    public searchRequest (string p1, long? p2) { //p2 type modified
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://test.com/", Order=0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string P1 

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://test.com/", Order=1)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public long2? P2
   }
}
```

By debugging, I can see that my SOAP xml request is (omitting soap tags):

```
<search>
    <P1>blah</P1>
    <P2 xsi:nill="true"></P2>
</search>
```

so, server is receiving a "" value for this element, but I want to remove  element from my request XML.

I've also a class search, which is included in knowntypes in my interface proxy class, but modifications in it has not effect (apparently).

EDIT:
This class have both a private long P2 property and a private bool P2Specified properties, but my proxy class does not have a method to pass a search class as a param, but only one with a searchRequest class param.

I've tested ShouldSerializeP2() in my class, P2Specified property in both classes, but I can't manage to avoid P2 tag generation.

Any Ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Usually when you generate proxies that have optional fields for un-nullable C# types (like 'long'), the proxy generator generates an additional boolean which has the field name suffixed by 'IsSpecified'. In your case that would be 'P2IsSpecified'. If that's not there, then check the WSDL to make sure that the field is indeed optional.

Comment: I tested service with SoapUI. The field is, indeed, optional. As I have edited, There is a second class, which has P2IsSpecified property, but I can't pass this class a parameter. How can I use this instead?

Comment: Why do you have two attributes with Order = 0?  Maybe that is causing the error.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo. Order values are 0 and 1.